# Push to git without an email address

Tags: git, jenkins, jgit

I'm using the jgit.sh on linux trying to push a file to the GIT repository via shell commands on Jenkins.

My Jenkins jobs will do the following:

- Fetch the git repo via Jenkins GIT Plugin
- I use some maven commands and additional files are created under the workspace.
- Use jgit.sh to push those files back to the git repository.

I'm executing the following commands:

```
jgit.sh checkout master
jgit.sh add ui5propreties.xml
jgit.sh commit -m "commit files"
jgit.sh push origin master
```

I'm using jgit.sh with a user called SolmanVoter and this user doesn't have an email address on git.
Just the User.

[image]

So I get the following error when I run the job:

```
remote: ERROR:  In commit d704a1f404f052f8117b456ac59a67a69cbfc281
remote: ERROR:  committer email address
remote: ERROR:  does not match your user account.
remote: ERROR:
remote: ERROR:  You have not registered any email addresses.
remote: ERROR:
remote: ERROR:  To register an email address, please visit:
remote: ERROR:  https://git.wdf.sap.corp/#/settings/contact
remote: 
To ssh://git.wdf.sap.corp:29418/sandbox/grcsandbox/pr1234_forcecommit.git
 ! [remote rejected] master -> master (invalid committer)
```

It's not possible to add an email address to the user SolmanVoter, so is there a way I make the push without the email address?

Comment: `jgit.sh` supports `commit -- author ...` but not `--committer` - apparently because native git doesn't have that option either. Why can't you just make up an email address for the Jenkins user? The email address does not necessarily have to exist.

Comment: Another workaround might be to run a shell command that adds a `[user]` section with the desired name and email to the config file of the cloned repository (i.e. `.git/config`).

Comment: @RüdigerHerrmann the problem is not with the jenkins user the issue is with the gerrit user SolmanVoter (the screenshot attached to my post). adding the email adress to the gerrit user is complicated (I have to go through a long process in my organization).
About the .git/config, Should I add the SolmanVoter with no email. Any idea how that works?

Comment: You could copy a predefined `config` file that contains the nexessary remotes, tracking branches and user settings if they are _constant_. Otherwise I'd use `sed` or some other Unix tool to manipulate the config file.